# How to Append Increments in a Function Individually to a List?

Tags: javascript, html

My issue is I am not sure how to type the code to increment `trainADistance`  by `trainAMPM` and decrease `trainBDistance` by `trainBMPM` in the `do` loop while having each `text` appended to the list. Each minute is supposed to be appended individually with  `text += "Minute " + i + " Train A Position: "+ parseFloat(trainADistance).toFixed(2) + " miles" + "Train B Position: " + parseFloat(trainBDistance).toFixed(2);`. An example is listed below.  Any help would be appreciated.

**What the function is supposed to do?**

The function I have been attempting to create is supposed to allow the user to input three variables `trainAMPH`, `trainBMPH` and `distanceApart`. When the inputs are submitted, the function `function calculateTrains()` is supposed to calculate `trainAMPH`, `trainBMPH`  into miles per minute `trainAMPM` and `trainBMPM`. There is a `do-while` loop in place to increment the minutes`i` , increment `trainADistance`  by `trainAMPM` and decrease `trainBDistance` by `trainBMPM`. `trainBDistance` is supposed to contain the same value as `distanceApart`. The loop continues `while(trainADistance < trainBDistance)` and is supposed to append `text` into a list until the loop is broken. An example is listed below.

**This is an example of what is supposed to be appended to to the list with inputs  70 for train A, 60 for train B and 260 for distance**

```
•   Minute 1 Train A Position: 1.17 miles Train B Position: 259.00 miles
•   Minute 2 Train A Position: 2.33 miles Train B Position: 258.00 miles
•   Minute 3 Train A Position: 3.50 miles Train B Position: 257.00 miles
•   Minute 4 Train A Position: 4.67 miles Train B Position: 256.00 miles
•   Minute 5 Train A Position: 5.83 miles Train B Position: 255.00 miles
```

**My Code**

```
<script>
        function calculateTrains(){

            let trainAMPH= document.getElementById("trainAMPH").value;
            let trainBMPH= document.getElementById("trainBMPH").value;
            let distanceApart = trainBDistance = document.getElementById("distanceApart").value;
            let list = document.getElementById("list");

            //calculates MPH into MPM(miles per minute)
            trainAMPM = (trainAMPH / 60);
            trainBMPM = (trainBMPH / 60);
            let trainADistance = 0;
            let text = "";
            let i = 0;
            let li = "";
            
            // do that increments the minutes and Train A/Train B's current position 
            d do{
            text += "Minute " + i + " Train A Position: "+ parseFloat(trainADistance).toFixed(2) + " miles" + "Train B Position: " + parseFloat(trainBDistance).toFixed(2);
            i++;
            trainADistance += parseFloat(trainAMPM);
            trainBDistance -= parseFloat(trainBMPM);
            li = document.createElement("li");
                
        }
        // while loop tht continues while Train A distance is less than Train B distance
        while(trainADistance < trainBDistance)

                //adds "text" variable listed in do while loop to list 
                li.innerHTML = text;
                list.appendChild(li);
            
            
            // documents the amount of minutes to the "results" div
            document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "The two trains met after " + i + "minutes.";
            }
    

    </script>
```

```
<body>
<form id="myForm">

        <label>Train A's Speed</label>
        <input id="trainAMPH" type="number" value="" placeholder="MPH">

        <label>Train B's Speed</label>
        <input id="trainBMPH" type="number" value="" placeholder="MPH" >

        <label>Distance between Eastford and Westford</label>
        <input id="distanceApart" type="number" value=""placeholder="Miles">

        <input  type ="button" value="Submit Values" onclick="calculateTrains()">

        <ul id = "list"></ul> 

        <div id="results"></div>


    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: What problem are you currently facing in your approach?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by this : `My second issue is I can't get trainBDistance to be recognized as a function.`? trainBDistance is supposed to be a variable not a function because you are trying to compare it with trainADistance, right?

Comment: ````trainBDistance.toFixed is not a function.````  is a syntax error I keep receiving. I am not sure why. I think it has to do with ````trainBDistance```` having the same value as ````distanceApart````.

Comment: The other error is how do I code a running list that involves doing addition and subtraction. Normally anytime we've incremented in class its always been ````(variable)++````. This one is new to me

Comment: trainBDistance is assigned to the value of your input element, which is of type string. Use parseFloat(trainBDistance).toFixed(2)

Comment: Awesome. Now my issue is how to append each ````item```` into individual bullets in the list as the example above?

Comment: Take a look at my answer, I've added a runnable code snippet, and also some in-line comments to explain how to approach the issue,  that should help you understand better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were some issue with the code, I have made the necessary changes. Please go through the in-line comments that I have added in order to understand what were the mistakes and how they can be fixed.

The code is working now, please use the below snippet to run and see it's output. Do make sure to see my comments. Goodluck!

```js
function calculateTrains() {
  let trainAMPH = +document.getElementById("trainAMPH").value;
  let trainBMPH = +document.getElementById("trainBMPH").value;
  let distanceApart, trainBDistance;
  //The input you retrieve using .value will be a string, convert it to Number using + to use toFixed
  distanceApart = trainBDistance = +document.getElementById("distanceApart")
    .value;
  let list = document.getElementById("list");

  //calculates MPH into MPM(miles per minute)
  trainAMPM = trainAMPH / 60;
  trainBMPM = trainBMPH / 60;
  let trainADistance = 0;
  let i = 1;
  let text = "";

  // do that increments the minutes and Train A/Train B's current position
  do {
      //don't use text+=, you don't want to append, you want each <li> to be on a separate line
    text =
      "Minute " +
      i +
      " Train A Position: " +
      trainADistance.toFixed(2) +
      " miles" +
      "Train B Position: " +
      trainBDistance.toFixed(2);
    
    //create list item using template literals
    let li = `<li>${text}</li>`;
    //use insertAdjaventHTML( ) function to append the above created literal to list <ul>
    list.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", li);
    //increment i
    i++;
    //do the train A and train B distance calculations
    //without these calculations, your while exit condition from below will never be met, 
    //making it an infinite while loop
    trainADistance += trainAMPM;
    trainBDistance -= trainBMPM;
  } while (
    // while loop tht continues while Train A distance is less than Train B distance
    trainADistance < trainBDistance
  );

  //don't use innerHTML to append text, innerHTML is to append HTML string like '<div> hello <div>' 
  //instead use textContent or innerText properties
  document.getElementById("results").textContent =
    "The two trains met after " + i + "minutes.";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <body>
      <form id="myForm">
        <label>Train A's Speed</label>
        <input id="trainAMPH" type="number" value="" placeholder="MPH" />
        <label>Train B's Speed</label>
        <input id="trainBMPH" type="number" value="" placeholder="MPH" />
        <label>Distance between Eastford and Westford</label>
        <input id="distanceApart" type="number" value="" placeholder="Miles" />
        <input
          type="button"
          value="Submit Values"
          onclick="calculateTrains()"
        />
        <ul id="list"></ul>
        <div id="results"></div>
      </form>
    </body>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I appreciate the comments and the time to help me understand this. I don't get much help in an online class.

Comment: I do have one question how to do I start Train A position at a distance? Since it is starting at one minute, the position should have a value other than zero?

Comment: Sure, just set the initial value of `trainADistance` as `trainAMPM`  like so : `let trainADistance = trainAMPM`;

Answer (score 1):

the reason why `trainBDistance.toFixed(2)` isn't recognized as a function is because when call `document.getElementById("distanceApart").value` the data type is string u need to `parseInt` or `parseFloat` that value first. You condition is `while(trainADistance < trainBDistance)` so you need to increment `trainADistance` as you said.

This might help.

```
function calculateTrains(){

    let trainAMPH= document.getElementById("trainAMPH").value;
    let trainBMPH= document.getElementById("trainBMPH").value;
    let distanceApart = trainBDistance = parseInt( document.getElementById("distanceApart").value );
    let list = document.getElementById("list");
    
    list.innerHTML = ''; //empty the list

    //calculates MPH into MPM(miles per minute)
    trainAMPM = (trainAMPH / 60);
    trainBMPM = (trainBMPH / 60);
    let trainADistance = 0;
    let i = 0;


    // do that increments the minutes and Train A/Train B's current position 
    do{
        let text = "Minute " + i + " Train A Position: "+ trainADistance.toFixed(2) + " miles" + " Train B Position: " + trainBDistance.toFixed(2);
        

        //adds "text" variable listed in do while loop to list 
        let li = document.createElement("li");
        li.innerHTML = text;
        list.appendChild(li);


        i++;

        trainADistance += trainAMPM; //increment trainADistance by trainAMPM
        trainBDistance -= trainBMPM; //decrease trainBDistance by trainBMPM
        
    }while(trainADistance < trainBDistance)
    // while loop tht continues while Train A distance is less than Train B distance

            
        
    // documents the amount of minutes to the "results" div
    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "The two trains met after " + i + "minutes."; 

}
```

Comment: This works as well. The only thing is the last code in the function ````document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "The two trains met after " + i + "minutes."; ```` doesn't display. Is it because its part of the while loop?

Comment: @chiecoman it does display on my machine. if ur using jsfiddle.net u might want to add ```<br/>```s after ```<div id="results"></div>``` coz the console might be covering that one.

Comment: Ah yes it is covering it up.

Answer (score 0):

You may wanna change you script to as follows:

```js
<script>
            function calculateTrains(){
                let trainAMPH= document.getElementById("trainAMPH").value;
                let trainBMPH= document.getElementById("trainBMPH").value;
                let distanceApart = trainBDistance = document.getElementById("distanceApart").value;
                let list = document.getElementById("list");
                trainAMPM = (trainAMPH / 60);
                trainBMPM = (trainBMPH / 60);
                let trainADistance = 0;
                let text = "";
                let i = 0;
                do{
                    i++;
                    trainADistance+=trainAMPM
                    trainBDistance-=trainBMPM
                    let li = document.createElement('li')
                    li.textContent="Minute " + i + " Train A Position: "+ parseFloat(trainADistance).toFixed(2) + " miles" + "Train B Position: " + parseFloat(trainBDistance).toFixed(2)
                    document.getElementById('list').appendChild(li)
                }while(trainADistance<=trainBDistance)
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to do a ````do-while```` loop as part of the assignment

Comment: I have changed my code in do-while loop style as you wanted.